# compile error: End If without block If (with more issues)

Tags: vba, compilation

Having an issue with below code. It says compile error when I run it, but I think I got bigger problems than that. What I am trying to accomplish:

1. Open the most recent "on hand report"
2. Go back to "Master KB-PFEP" worksheet
3. If the worksheet has a filter on, clear the filter
4. Do a VLOOKUP to update the on hand column from the on hand report

Thank you very much for your help

```
    Dim curDate As String, Fname As String
    curDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Dim wba As Workbook
    Fname = "Y:\Consumables\Company\ABC\ABC - Planning & Materials\On Hand Reports\ABC Site\" & curDate & "_INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx"
    Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Fname, UpdateLinks:=False, Notify:=False)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "*Master KB-PFEP" Then wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets("Master").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    If (Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilterMode And Worksheets("Master Data").FilterMode) Or Worksheets("Master Data").FilterMode Then
    Worksheets("Master Data").ShowAllData
    End If
    Range("AL8:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF('Inv Report'!C[-36],RC[-36],'Inv Report'!C[-21])"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a `For Each` loop, but I don't see `Next`, is it missing from your pasting or actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you should have is below (have not checked your R1C1 values):

1. A new line on `wb.Activate`
2. Use `FormulaR1C1` instead of `Formula`
3. Added `Next` before `End Sub`

---

```
Sub SO_30042563()
    Dim curDate As String, Fname As String
    curDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Dim wba As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Fname = "Y:\Consumables\Company\ABC\ABC - Planning & Materials\On Hand Reports\ABC Site\" & curDate & "_INV_R12_ABC_Onhandreport.xlsx"
    Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Fname, UpdateLinks:=False, Notify:=False)
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*Master KB-PFEP" Then
            wb.Activate
            wb.Worksheets("Master").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
            If (Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilterMode And Worksheets("Master Data").FilterMode) Or Worksheets("Master Data").FilterMode Then
                Worksheets("Master Data").ShowAllData
            End If
            Range("AL8:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('Inv Report'!C[-36],RC[-36],'Inv Report'!C[-21])"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above code. No error codes, but the macro stopped afer it opened wba, but did not activate wb and carry on.

Comment: That's most likely because your `wb.Name Like "*Master KB-PFEP"` never return true. Either no workbooks ending with **Master KB-PFEP** (case sensitive) or you need `wb.Worksheets("Master Data")`. Also I don't see any use of **wba** after you have opened it.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. However, I must have coded the formula incorrectly. I will have to post as separate question. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `End If` when the conditional code is on the same line:

```
If wb.Name Like "*Master KB-PFEP" Then wb.Activate
```

That means you have an extra one at the bottom. After you fix that, you'll need to add the missing `Next` somewhere before the `End Sub`.